# What has replaced ServiceResolver.GetFilterProviders() in ASP.NET WebAPI RC?

Tags: castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api

I have some code that's using a custom filter provider to perform property injection using Windsor on my action filters in a WebAPI project.

I'm just upgrading it from WebAPI beta to WebAPI RC, and I have a method in my container registration that used to read:

```
container.Register(
  Component
    .For<IEnumerable<IFilterProvider>>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(
      () => GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.GetFilterProviders()
    )
);
```

This would allow me to get the 'default' collection of filter providers and pass that into my custom filter provider, which would in turn retrieve the filters from each default provider, inject any missing dependencies via property injection, and return the filter with dependencies resolved.

In ASP.NET WebAPI RC, the ServiceResolver is now DependencyResolver and no longer has a GetFilterProviders() method - what should I be using in its place?

**EDIT:** Right, the following registration syntax is working - as in, it's passing all the unit tests and doesn't appear to be leaking memory or anything - but I'm not sure that explicitly binding to the instance returned by the Services.FilterProviders() is a good idea...

```
var filterProviders = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders();
container.Register(
   Component.For<IEnumerable<IFilterProvider>>().Instance(filterProviders),
   Component.For<IFilterProvider>().ImplementedBy<WindsorFilterProvider>()
);
```

and, for the sake of completeness, the WindsorFilterProvider looks like this:

```
public class WindsorFilterProvider : IFilterProvider {
  private readonly IWindsorContainer container;
  private readonly IEnumerable<IFilterProvider> filterProviders;

  public WindsorFilterProvider(IWindsorContainer container, IEnumerable<IFilterProvider> filterProviders) {
    this.container = container;
    this.filterProviders = filterProviders;
  }

  public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) {            
    var filters = filterProviders.SelectMany(fp => fp.GetFilters(configuration, actionDescriptor)).ToList();
    foreach (var filter in filters) container.Inject(filter.Instance);
    return filters;
  }
}
```

I guess the question is - is this a good way of doing this, or is there a recommended approach that I should be using instead?

Comment: I am confused. You seem to be using Windsor for the filter providers only and not for the whole. Is that true?

Comment: No, we're using Windsor for everything - I've overridden the frameworks' DependencyResolver with a WindsorDependencyResolver we've created. This example just shows how it's being used with filter providers...